# Mock statically imported class in Angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I am using facebook SDK in my Angular application for which I am importing the FB SDK class like below

```
import MiniAppSDKClient from 'src/clients/MiniAppSDKClient';
```

After this I am using below method of that class to get some information

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Get data from Facebook SDK
    const entryPointData = MiniAppSDKClient.getEntryPointData();
  }
```

During testing I want to mock the **getEntryPointData** method of that class. Can't find any way to mock above class or that particular method of that class. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: One possible way would be to wrap the Facebook client in an Angular service, then mock that using the DI system like you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to update the code so `MiniAppSDKClient` should be injected.

However, if you cannot change the code, you can use `beforeEach` and `afterEach` like that:

```js
describe('suite', () => {
  let getEntryPointDataBackup;

  beforeEach(() => getEntryPointDataBackup = MiniAppSDKClient.getEntryPointData);
  afterEach(() => MiniAppSDKClient.getEntryPointData = getEntryPointDataBackup);

  // your normal beforeEach here.

  it('test', () => {
    MiniAppSDKClient.getEntryPointData = () => myMockEntryPointData;

    // the rest of your code.
  });
});
```

### The right way

create a root token which provides `MiniAppSDKClient` and simply mock it in TestBed:

```js
export const MINI_APP_SDK_CLIENT = new InjectionToken('MINI_APP_SDK_CLIENT', {
  factory: () => MiniAppSDKClient,
  providedIn: 'root',
});
```

Your component / directive / service should use DI:

```js
class TargetComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(MINI_APP_SDK_CLIENT) client: typeof MiniAppSDKClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Get data from Facebook SDK
    const entryPointData = this.client.getEntryPointData();
  }
}
```

its test:

```js
describe('suite', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [TargetComponent],
    providers: [{
      provide: MINI_APP_SDK_CLIENT,
      useValue: {
        getEntryPointData: () => {
          return myFakeEntryPointData;
        },
      },
    }],
  }).compileComponents());
});
```

Profit!